# Vue image Src binding not showing

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

Hello I was creating an upload Image but I have incounter an issue on preview image I have seen this solution and tried to replicate the File is selected and Blob URL is seen but I am having an issue on the URL and update Here is the link for the article. Also if posible to change the upload to target only Image files.

[Seen solution for Upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49106045/preview-an-image-before-it-is-uploaded-vuejs?answertab=active#tab-top)

HTML code

```
  <input type="file" @change="uploadImageChange"/>
          <div class="dashboard-Image-modal__previewUploadImage">
              <img if="imageSelectedUrl" :src="imageSelectedUrl"/>
          </div>
```

Method

```
data(){
return {
   imageSelectedUrl:null
};
    },

methods:{
uploadImageChange(e){
      const file = e.target.files[0];
      this.imageSelectedUrl = URL.createObjectURL(file);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code works fine for me: https://jsfiddle.net/teddyrised/eq49yd6m/

Answer (score 0):

I think i found the problem, you write:

```
data(){
   return {
       imageSelectedUrl:null
   },
```

you missed `}`.
Try to write:

```
data () {
        return {
            imageSelectedUrl: null
        }
    },
```

Comment: ah sorry i just mistype that when i was transferring the code here. But on my application it has.